# Batch script to make backup folder. only new and modified files

Tags: batch-file, backup, xcopy

I need a script to copy only the changed/modified and new files from my C:\Dropbox to my C:\backup. Why does this copy only the folder structure:

```
@echo off

set destination=C:\Backup
set source=C:\Users\XXXX\Dropbox\Intranet

for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd1=%%j"."%%i"."%%k

xcopy %source%"\*" %destination%"\*" /m/e/y
mkdir %destination%"\LastBackupDate %yyyymmdd1%"
echo A folder containing the latest date has been created in root directory of %source%.
echo Finished copying %source% to %destination%
echo.
pause
```

Comment: For someone who wants a free tool, there is rubocopy for windows/*nix, and a nice tool with gui named SyncToy (part of power toys)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ECHO OFF
set source=C:\Users\xxxx\Dropbox\
set destination=C:\Backup\

for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd1=%%j"."%%i"."%%k

if exist %destination% goto GO
:GO
mkdir %destination%%yyyymmdd1%
xcopy %source%* %destination% /s/d/y/c/v/r
echo. 
echo Finished copying %source% to %destination%
echo.
echo Created %destination%%yyyymmdd1%
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic backup script.

```
@echo off
REM get start time
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

REM set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
set "logtimestamp=%YYYY%.%MM%.%DD% %HH%:%Min%:%Sec%"

REM actual copy
set source=%1
set destination=%2

REM create the exclusion list
set exclusion=%3
set exclusion=%exclusion:"=%
(for %%i in (%exclusion%) do echo %%i) > exclusion.txt

REM set the file name for the logging data
set log=log-%fullstamp%.txt

REM start the backup process
echo // started backup at %logtimestamp% > %log%
echo // from %~f1 to %~f2\ >> %log%

echo ---- >> %log%
xcopy %source% %destination% /S /E /C /D /H /R /Y /V /I /EXCLUDE:exclusion.txt >> %log%
echo ---- >> %log%
del /f exclusion.txt

REM get finish time
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "logtimestamp=%YYYY%.%MM%.%DD% %HH%:%Min%:%Sec%"

echo // finished backup at %logtimestamp% >> %log%

REM move the logging
if not exist "%destination%\.backup_log" mkdir %destination%\.backup_log
move %log% %destination%\.backup_log
```

The way I would call it, assuming the batch script is called backup.bat:

```
backup.bat MyFolder h:\MyFolder .metadata
```

Where the content of MyFolder gets backuped to the h:\MyFolder and all folders called '.metadata' are ignored. The Folder 'MyFolder' on the h:\ drive gets created if not already available.

Features of this script:

- Creates all necessary folders
- Copies all files if they were modified since last backup
- Creates a folder for logging within the destination folder data called: .backup_log
- Creates a log-file containing all info while xcopy is running and timestamp of starting and stopping time.

Update:
If you have no exclusion list put "" as third parameter.

Comment: And How would one restore from the backup?

Comment: you are right. just replace rm with del. rm is from cygwin.

Comment: I'd recommend `del /f /q` so there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

TO answer the original question, why your script copied just the folder structure...

It was due the parameters on the xcopy, you specified just these /m/e/y:

> /M = Copies only files with the archive attribute set, turns off the archive attribute.
>
> /E = Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
>
> /Y = Suppress confirmations.

Notice that as the answer given before, just by adding /D and removing /M it will make the trick, please check what the help says about /D:

> /D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
>                  If no date is given, copies only those files whose
>                  source time is newer than the destination time.

In case you need to back up multiple folders in one run and have a log file with their executions, you can have something like this:

```
@echo off

call:backUpFolder "C:\Users\XXX\folder1" "C:\Backup\folder1"
call:backUpFolder "C:\Users\XXX\folder2" "C:\Backup\folder2"
call:backUpFolder "C:\Users\XXX\folder3" "C:\Backup\folder3"

goto:eof
::--------------------------------------------------
::-- This is the function to back up one folder
::--------------------------------------------------
:backUpFolder
set source="%~1"
set destination="%~2"
echo copying from %source% to %destination%

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2% %ldt:~8,2%:%ldt:~10,2%:%ldt:~12,6%

xcopy %source%"\*" %destination%"\*" /s/d/y/c/v/r

echo %ldt%: %source% to %destination% >> backHistory.log
echo Finished copying %source% to %destination%
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set "source="F:\Projects""
set "destination=G:\backup"

for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
if not exist %destination%\%datestr% (mkdir %destination%\%datestr%)

for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^|find "20"') do set dt=%%I
set dt=%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%-%dt:~0,4%
echo %dt%

XCOPY %source% %destination%\%datestr% /S /d:%dt% /Y

REM XCOPY %source% %destination%\%datestr% /E /I /H /Y /S /d:%dt%

pause
"Press any key to continue . . ."
```