# Command Prompt/Bat file - Create new folder named with today's date

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I use the following code to create a new folder that is named with todays date:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%a in ('date /T') do set datestr=%%a
mkdir c:\%date:/=%
```

Now the format is as follows:

```
20130619
```

How do I change the format to?:

```
2013_06_19
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do md "%%a_%%b_%%c"
```

Answer (score 23):

%date% depends on your computer settings, and locale.  Here is a reliable way to get a date and time stamp.  Win XP pro and above.

If you need to use your batch file on unknown machines then this is worth using.

```
:: time and date stamp YYYYMMDD, HHMMSS and YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo stamp: "%stamp%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"

pause
```

Comment: at last someone who does not rely on the locale-dependent %date% !

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd1="%%k"_"%%i"_"%%j"
mkdir %yyyymmdd1%
```

Comment: taken from a previous answer that might help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280077/batch-script-to-make-backup-folder-only-new-and-modified-files/ - just see how i manipulate the "%%i" or %%k or %%j and the _ between them

Comment: thanks, but your answer only shows the month and day in the folder name, not the year...test it

Comment: hi, it shows it all maybe you didnt copy paste the whole line :)  my answer is as the one you accepted. it is identical and original

Answer (score 2):

or simply

```
SET Today=%Date:~10,4%_%Date:~7,2%_%Date:~4,2%

echo %today%
```

outputs

```
2013_06_19
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Then you could easily use the variable today for directory creation e.g.:

```
mkdir %today%
```

EDIT: YYYY_MM_DD format

Comment: with your code as it is currently, it retuns 'today' as the folder name

Comment: yes, is not that what you wanted? you can concat drive letter or other part of path. This solution does not contain any for loops