# CMD echo %date% returns '/Tu' instead of a proper date

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd

I am generating the date in a format of YYYYMMDD so that i can append it in the filename that the batch program generates.

But in my local system echo %date% returns

```
echo %date%
Tue 09/08/2015
```

The date information is returned so i can modify it the way i want

In server, the same does not return date values

```
echo %date%
 /Tu
```

I dont have date values to modify it to my required format YYYYMMDD

How do I go about this? Is there any Windows date and time setting that i should be looking at?

Comment: It probably depends on regional settings and possibly versions of Windows (on my UK-English XP and Win7 systems, both return `08/09/2015`).  The second result looks odd though: check you haven't got an environment variable masking the value (run `set d` to see if `date` is listed).

Comment: This may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184242/command-prompt-bat-file-create-new-folder-named-with-todays-date/17186963#17186963

Comment: @TripeHound `Environment variable d not defined` is the Output of `set d`

Comment: That means you haven't got an explicit `DATE` variable overriding the built-in `%DATE%` function.  I'd probably follow the answer foxidrive linked to.as it eliminates regional variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format depends on the regional settings of your machine. You can check them in control panel (run `intl.cpl`), they seem to be broken.