# Make a folder with today's date with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am fairly new with creating batch files.

I have made a batch file with the following content:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Runtime Software\DriveImage XML\dixml.exe" /bC /c /l /t"B:\DRIVE IMAGES\Windows10_maintenance_backup
```

This allows me to run DriveImage XML and take a backup simply by running the bat file.

I would like the bat file to automatically make a folder with today's date so that:

```
B:\DRIVE IMAGES\Windows10_maintenance_backup
```

Becomes:

```
B:\DRIVE IMAGES\2016.01.20\Windows10_maintenance_backup
```

How can I achieve this by editing the .bat file?
I have had a look at foxidrives solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186963/2154717) but I do not know how to implement the solution.

Comment: This question was previously answered with a method that is region independent.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work on all computers. `WMIC` needs to be run by an administrator before a normal user can use it.

Comment: vMax's solution from that page is the one I would use.  You assumed the checked one.

Comment: Yeah, I just used vMax solution and it works. I would like to show the final result but now the post is marked as a duplicate so I don't know if I should.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo    md B:\DRIVE IMAGES\%date:~-4%.%date:~7,2%.%date:~4,2%\windows10\etc
```

See `set /?` for help on substring extraction.

This assumes date is in following format

Thu 21/01/2016

Comment: What does md stand for?

Comment: it's the make directory (`md` or `mkdir`) command, I am echoing so they can see the command without actually executing it. See `md /?` and `echo /?`. Also type help.

Comment: Sorry this did not work at all. I have no idea how to implement this in the following line: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Runtime Software\DriveImage XML\dixml.exe" /bC /c /l /t"B:\DRIVE IMAGES\Windows10_maintenance_backup`